# AppID "CC1AD845" for Default Media receiver doesn't work

Tags: google-cast, chromecast

I tried use AppId "CC1AD845" in my android cast sender app. However, cast device didn't loaded any default media cast receiver.html, it still is on the Chromecast HomeScreen Page.

I changed it to my own whitelisted AppId and device load my receiver.html successfully.

"CC1AD845" is the constant value of `CastMediaControlIntent.DEFAULT_MEDIA_RECEIVER_APPLICATION_ID`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using the official Cast SDK for Android?? That has not yet been published, so I am assuming  you are using the preview SDK. Please clarify. You cannot use the new app ids (such as the one you had mentioned) with the preview SDK.

Comment: Yes, I take the old GoogleCastSDK. Thank you!

Comment: Is there some way that we can still register under the old system?

If not how are we supposed to develop Android sender apps for Chromecasts we didn't register before the SDK release, given that Google Play Services 15 won't be out for some time and we can't use the preview SDK with newly registered devices!?

Comment: Alex, registering under old system would only work with the preview SDK which would not be want you to do any longer. We are getting closer to the release of SDK but till that is released, you can only develop an end-to-end app for iOS and web (of course you can read the documentation on Android SDK). For a serious app, I assure you that there is plenty of UI work that can happen without having the SDK, in case you want to start right now.

Comment: It's not much help if you already made your app on the preview SDK and you're trying to install it on a newly purchased Chromecast though ;).

Thanks for the answer though @AliNaddaf - I really do appreciate all the prompt answers you've given for Google Cast questions on SO, even if they haven't always been what I wanted to hear :).

Comment: @AlexGilleran : Check the Android SDK Manager - I pulled Revision 15 last night.